# Visual Studio Windows Form App where is the Form constructor being called

Tags: visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

My problem is that I can see the form I make properly on the [Design] page, but when I run the program it shows a blank page. The reason it happens is because `"InitializeComponent()"` is not being called.

Yet, I do have it on my constructor so I made a console message there to check if I even get to the constructor and I do not for some reason, it used to work well before I changed my form to a MetroForm and now even if I change it back to a normal form it won't work.

But now, since I know the problem is the constructor not even called, my question is: What class and, where inside this class the Form constructor is being called?

***Note: Visual Studio does not show any errors on any class whatsoever.***

***If you want to see parts of the code just tell me which class you would like to see and I will send it***

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into something similar.  I was not compiling against the right version of .NET.
Select your project, Right click and select Properties, Click Application, Select the Target framework for the version of .NET you wish to compile against.

Comment: The compiling used to work, and now it doesn't, and I noticed the constructor is not being called thus I suspect something is not right specifically there, perhaps because I changed names of both Form and class? Could it make that problem? does a class or a Form has to be named in a specific name?

And When I say used to work I mean right until I sent that question, before that it worked perfectly.